# PRO B550M-P GEN3 MB W/ RYZEN 7 5700X CPU

Tags: ssd, display, cpu, motherboard, signal

I'm hoping someone can assist me. I've upgraded my MB & CPU to the following PRO B550M-P GEN3 MB  W/ RYZEN 7 5700X CPU. I've also added more RAM from 32 to 128. Along with a new 700W PSU.

I'm using an SSD 2TB w/ SATA connection drive which I used on my older MSI MB without issues.

I've connected everything properly and triple checked the connections including ensuring the RAM cards are properly in place. I've rechecked the PSU connectors to the MB and all is well.

I've also checked multiple times to ensure the CPU is set properly with an appropriate amount of Thermal Compound. I've re-checked the SSD drive connection, tried different cables and connector slots.

Lastly, I reconnected the SATA drive I cloned to the SSD and that powers up.

Issue: Everything turns on fine. The Fans are working, the MB light is on. The front panel connections / I/O switch / lights are working. My PC has a CD ROM drive and that is working.

However, the monitors are showing **"No Signal".** Monitor Cables are connected properly. I pulled the SSD and reconnected the SATA drive I cloned to the SSD and that powers up, but still nothing on the monitors. I'm hoping someone has a recommendation I can try for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The RYZEN 7 5700X does NOT have on-die GPU. You need a graphics card, or a processor that has GPU capabilities.

Check the section "Graphics capabilities": https://www.amd.com/en/product/11826

List of 5000 series desktop models (at bottom of page) which indicates which ones have GPU capabilities: https://www.amd.com/en/processors/ryzen

Comment: Thank you for this...Much appreciate it!